# Github actions: should I test my python project with pytest or with tox?

Tags: pytest, github-actions, tox

I have a Python project that is automatically tested with the following Github Actions file:

```
name: pytest

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 4
      matrix:
        python: ["3.8", "3.9"]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python }}
      - name: Install pytest
        run: python -m pip install pytest
      - name: Install requirements
        run: python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
      - name: Run pytest
        run: python -m pytest
```

It works fine, but I saw that other projects use an action for `tox`, which then runs `pytest`. I understand that `tox` automatically installs a virtual environment, but this is already done by GitHub Actions.

Is there a reason to replace my current Github Actions file with a file that runs `tox`?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `tox` both local and on CI/GHA, so you can test your code against several Python versions without duplicating any test setups.

That is the main benefit.

PS: I am one of the `tox` maintainers.